# Spring Boot autowire MBean?

Tags: spring-boot, jmx, autowired, spring-jmx

Spring Boot won't autowire a MBean I exported from another web application with:

```
@Component
@Service
@ManagedResource(objectName = IHiveService.MBEAN_NAME)
public class HiveService implements IHiveService {
    @Autowired(required = true)
    CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @Override
    @ManagedOperation
    public String echo(String input) {
        return "you said " + input;
    }
}
```

I can see and use the Bean in Oracle Java Mission Control but the other Spring Boot app is not able to autowire the bean. I this I missed an annotation. To autowire the bean I use:

```
@Controller
@Configuration 
@EnableMBeanExport
public class GathererControls {
   @Autowired
   IHiveService hiveService; // <-- this should be auto wired
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `@Controller` and `@Configuration` in the same class?? Is that possible?

Comment: @PauChorro i got desperate and tried everything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `@EnableMBeanExport` annotation in the application where you want to access the management bean from the original application.

What you do need is a connection to the JMX registry to get access to the exported (by the first app) management objects.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public MBeanProxyFactoryBean hiveServiceFactory() {
    MBeanProxyFactoryBean proxyFactory = new MBeanProxyFactoryBean();
    proxyFactory.setObjectName(IHiveService.MBEAN_NAME);
    proxyFactory.setProxyInterface(IHiveService.class);
    proxyFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return proxyFactory;
  }

  @Bean 
  public IHiveService hiveService(MBeanProxyFactoryBean hiveServiceFactory) {
    return (IHiveService) hiveServiceFactory.getObject();
  }
}
```

Now in your controller:

```
@Controller
public class GathererControls {
   @Autowired
   IHiveService hiveService; // <-- will be autowired
   // ...
   // ...
}
```

Comment: you are my personal hero :) It's working! Thank you very much.